# Are SVG parameters such as 'xmlns' and 'version' needed?

Tags: xml, svg, tags

In about half of the svg examples I see on the internet, the code is wrapped in plain simple `<svg></svg>` tags.

In the other half, the svg tags have lots of complicated attributes like this:

```
<svg 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  version="1.1" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

My question is: is it ok to use the simple svg tags? I've tried playing around with the complicated ones, and everything works fine at my end if I don't include them.

Answer (score 282, accepted):

All user agents (browsers) ignore the version attribute, so you can always drop that.

If you embed your SVG inline in a HTML page and serve that page as `text/html` then [xmlns attributes are not required](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#foreign-elements). Embedding SVG inline in HTML documents is a fairly recent innovation that came along as part of HTML5.

If however you serve your page as image/svg+xml or application/xhtml+xml or any other MIME type that causes the user agent to use an XML parser then [the xmlns attributes **are** required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course). This was the only way to do things until recently so there is a lot of content served like this.

Comment: *"All UAs ignore the version attribute, so you can always drop that."* - but what does spec have to say about the matter? "Browsers will let you get away with it" is (or has at some point been) true of many practices that are (or were) unambiguously incorrect.

Comment: In IE11, if I put `<!DOCTYPE svg xmlns="www.w3.org/2000/svg">` it works, but if I take away the xmlns or change it to `<!DOCTYPE svg xmlns="www.example.com">` it doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: @RobertLongson : When you say "the xmlns attributes," does that include xmlns:xlink?

Comment: Would the "Embedding SVG inline in HTML documents" part also hold true to css files, when using data-uri's?

Comment: @Marcel not if those data-uris are  image/svg+xml, which is usually the case, then the final part of the answer holds.

Comment: @DonaldDuck FYI, if the SVG is inline (ie within the HTML), the doctype doesn't have to be included if you've already defined a doctype at the top of your HTML page.

Comment: @SC_Chupacabra Any `xmlns:` attributes just declares a prefix for a namespace. You don't need any of that if you don't use the prefix. So if your SVG doesn't have `xlink:` attributes, it's unnecessary. As in every XML document.

Answer (score 348):

The `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` attribute is:

- **Required** for **image/svg+xml** files. <sup>1</sup>
- **Optional** for **inlined** `<svg>`. <sup>2</sup>

The `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` attribute is:

- **Required** for **image/svg+xml** files with **xlink:** attributes. <sup>1</sup>
- **Optional** for **inlined** `<svg>` with **xlink:** attributes. <sup>2</sup>

The `version="1.1"` attribute is:

- **Recommended** to comply with **image/svg+xml** files standards. <sup>3</sup>
- **Apparently ignored** by every user agent. <sup>4</sup>
- **Removed** in SVG 2. <sup>5</sup>

<sup>1</sup> [Internationalized Resource Identifiers (RFC3987)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3987.txt)
<sup>2</sup> [Since HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/)
<sup>3</sup> [Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/)
<sup>4</sup> Probably until the release of further major versions.
<sup>5</sup> [SVG 2, W3C Candidate Recommendation, 07 August 2018](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-SVG2-20180807/changes.html#structure)

Comment: Does it need to be http or can it be https as well?

Comment: @JohannesB both protocols are compatible :D

Comment: Are you sure about it? [This post](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/#mixed-content-from-us) of Nick Craver implies something else, which is the reason I asked this question in the first place (because it seemed illogical to me).

Comment: @JohannesB yes here you have an **inlined** example [HTTP](http://ncomputers.org) [HTTPS](https://ncomputers.org) and **image/svg+xml** file with **inlined** svg with **xlink** attributes example [HTTP](http://ncomputers.org/content) [HTTPS](https://ncomputers.org/content)

Comment: Thanks, guess Nick Craver makes mistakes as well then ;)

Comment: @JohannesB ooo ... i guess i understood your question now: you can host an **inlined** SVG or **file** with **http** and **https** protocols. some tests showed me that the **xmlns attribute has to be http**. it is only a **resource identifier** string and the browser doesn't include those URLs :D

Comment: What about when you serve SVGs using a `data:` URL (either as an attribute value in HTML, or in CSS)? Is the `xmlns` required then? (Does that count as 'inline'?)

Comment: Do not mistake the `version` attribute of the xml declaration (`<?xml version...`)  for the `version` attribute of the `<svg>` element. The first one is about the version of the XML markup language, while the latter one specifies the version of SVG. The author of this answer made that mistake by refering to the XML, not the SVG specification in ³. I tried to correct it, but some idiotes rejected the edit.

Comment: There is no mention of `xmlns`in the reference 2. Could you update the answer?

Comment: To echo zrajm's question, what about `background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg...` in CSS ?

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to add to both answers, but I have no points, I'm adding a new answer.
In recent tests on Chrome (Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit Windows)), I have found that:

1. For inline SVG that is directly entered into the HTML file, via text editor or javascript and elm.innerHTML, the xmlns attributes are not necessary, as stated in the other two answers.
2. But for inline SVG that is loaded via javascript and AJAX, there are two options:

   - Use `xhr.responseText` and `elm.innerHTML`. This does not require the xmlns.
   - Use `xhr.responseXML.documentElement` and `elm.appendChild()` or `elm.insertBefore()`. This method of creating the inline SVG produces half-baked results without the basic SVG namespace being declared, as in `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`. The <svg> loads into the HTML, but document-level functions, such as `getElementById()` are not recognized on the <svg> element. I assume that this is because it uses the XMLHttpRequest XML parser outside of the HTML.

Answer (score 4):

About SVG version attribute the MDN [WebDoc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/version) says

> **Deprecated since SVG 2**
>  This feature is no longer recommended. Though
>   some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed
>   from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being
>   dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using
>   it, and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table
>   at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this
>   feature may cease to work at any time.
>
> The version attribute is used to indicate what specification a SVG
>   document conforms to. It is only allowed on the root  element. It
>   is purely advisory and has no influence on rendering or processing.

PS: The SVG 2 is far from becoming a standard yet.

Comment: Note: the above only applies to the "version" attribute, not "xmlns"

xmlns is an XML (not SVG) feature and as such in HTML5 (when not used as XML/XHTML) it is not relevant or needed but in SVG embedded in XML for any reason it would be