# Correct way to store gloabl SVG Style (radialGradient)

Tags: css, svg, styles

where do i put this stylecodes?

```
<radialGradient gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" r="100%" cy="50%" cx="50%" id="rgrad_group_43">
   <stop style="stop-color:rgb(0, 255, 244); stop-opacity:1" offset="0%"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:rgb(0, 74, 255); stop-opacity:1" offset="90%"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:rgb(46, 60, 208); stop-opacity:1" offset="100%"/>
</radialGradient>

<style type="text/css">
svg rect { fill:transparent;}
svg g { fill:url(#rgrad_group_43); }
</style>
```

When i put the code in the body, no svgs on my page where styled.
So i must put it into an SVG tag, right?

```
<svg>
<radialGradient gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" r="100%" cy="50%" cx="50%" id="rgrad_group_43">
   <stop style="stop-color:rgb(0, 255, 244); stop-opacity:1" offset="0%"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:rgb(0, 74, 255); stop-opacity:1" offset="90%"/>
   <stop style="stop-color:rgb(46, 60, 208); stop-opacity:1" offset="100%"/>
</radialGradient>

<style type="text/css">
svg rect { fill:transparent;}
svg g { fill:url(#rgrad_group_43); }
</style>
</svg>
```

It works but is this correct/valid?
No `version="1.1"` , no  `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` no  `viewBox="0 0 50 50"` and no  `xml:space="preserve"`

here is a demo 
https://jsfiddle.net/qcmxryay/

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467982/are-svg-parameters-such-as-xmlns-and-version-needed/18468348#18468348

Answer (score -2):

i don't sure if Works for you, but to me work, always i going to work with a SVG, i make the figure or anything in Illustrator and then i use the option export like SVG, so i don't need make that kind of changes.