# What could be stopping an .svg file importing into <section> tags of .php file?

Tags: php, html, svg

While putting together a web-page, I have been running into some issues with the SVG file I am trying to include.

The SVG works fine when I type the code straight into the section tags in my .php file, but this is not ideal, as I intend to attach an if statement to determine which one SVG file will display, out of several options.

So my thinking is it would be easier to store each differing SVG design in its own .svg file, but when I point to the file I receive the same error message on the web-page when I run the code. 
This is the error: [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSmTr.png) (I have addressed the error and changed what is on line 6, with no success)

I have found articles online on this subject, some of which are outdated by 7-8 years. The articles that did prove useful offered 3 options.

1. To use an object tag.
   This was my first choice as I want to interact with the svgs objects via JS, which the info I could find online said that this was the best way to do that.

This option didn't work, giving the above error I have shared. 
Here is the code from the .php page:

```
<section id="section-shape-1" class="">
 <object type="image/svg+xml" data="circles16.svg" width="66%" height="100vh" border="1">
    </object></section>
```

Here is the SVG code(located in .svg file):

```
<svg id="group1" width="66%" height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 700 666">

<circle id="circle0" class="circle" cx="170" cy="125" r="20" fill="#1dacf9" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" onclick="changeColor()"/> </svg>
```

2. Use an iFrame.

I tried to use the iFrame tag, against some of the advice of the forums I read, and this proved to yield the same error message as before.

3. Use IMG tags.

This was at the bottom of the list, purely because the info I was reading suggested that this option means I couldn't interact via JS. 
Regardless, it still didn't work.

Other things I tried included changing the DOCTYPE at the top of the file I wished to import, with no success. 
Also tried changing the extension of the file from .svg to .xml, with neither of these working.

Now I am hoping to have someone on here spot where I am going wrong, any advice would be great, as everything I have so far tried hasn't worked.

Comment: It sure would be nice to see some problematic code...

Comment: The other code involved is just the <svg> code which is saved in the circles16.svg file, this code just describes the shape and properties of the svg. It works fine by itself. The only issue I'm having is with importing the .svg file, through the code posted above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @deefour Im not sure how you would have me edit it any further, I have described all the moving parts, and included as little code as possible. The only problematic code is that which I've posted above. Maybe I should ask how you would go about importing an .svg file into a .php file? Rather than try to describe what I have tried.

Comment: You should provide the minimal amount of code necessary to allow the community you're asking for help to reproduce your problem. It's really that simple. I can take that `<object>` tag and any random SVG off the internet, drop it into an HTML file and won't be able to reproduce the issue **you** are having. Help us help you.

Comment: @deefour Okay if you check above then I have included the other code from the .svg file. If you were to take any SVG and make it show up in any HTML file, I would be interested to know how that was done, as that is the issue I'm having.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `xmlns` (xml namespace) attribute on your SVG.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="group1" width="66%" height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 700 666">
    <circle id="circle0" class="circle" cx="170" cy="125" r="20" fill="#1dacf9" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" onclick="changeColor()"/>
</svg>
```

The image won't render as an SVG in browsers without this when embedded. [Here is a relevant SO answer with more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18468348/605707).

Comment: Yeah this seems to have done the trick. Thank you for your help

Comment: Please accept the answer if it fixed your problem. Also, I hope this was a good exercise for you in what an MCVE is for a question here on SO. The more info you provide that *directly* targets the problem, the quicker/more likely you'll be to get help.