# How to create an ellipse in svg

Tags: html, svg

I'm trying to add an ellipse in a SVG

*(original snippet)*

```html
    <svg>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></rect>
      <circle cx="200" cy="0" r="100"></circle>
      <ellipse cx="400" cy="0" rx="100" ry="50" fill="yellow"></ellipse>
    </svg>
```

But adding some attributes works:

*(working snippet)*

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></rect>
      <circle cx="200" cy="0" r="100"></circle>
      <ellipse cx="400" cy="0" rx="100" ry="50" fill="yellow"></ellipse>
    </svg>
```

Questions:

1. What are the attributes of `xmlns` and `version` for?
2. Why is the ellipse NOT showing up in the original snippet (but the rect and the circle show up properly)?

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jeffxiao/qa4ujnrk/) for a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't provide a canvas size the `<svg>` element (same as all replaced elements) defaults to [300px](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width) x [150px](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height). Your ellipse is at rx="400" so is outside the canvas. Setting a larger canvas size fixes thing so you can see the ellipse.

[version is pointless, xmlns is only required for standalone SVG files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18468348/1038015), if you're embedding things in an html page as we're doing here with snippets you can omit both.

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></rect>
    <circle cx="200" cy="0" r="100"></circle>
    <ellipse cx="400" cy="0" rx="100" ry="50" fill="yellow"></ellipse>
</svg>
```

Comment: Excellent answer in all senses.

Answer (score 1):

What prevents the ellipse from displaying is the lack of `width` attribute, as this snippet illustrates:

```html
<svg width="350">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></rect>
  <circle cx="200" cy="0" r="100"></circle>
  <ellipse cx="400" cy="0" rx="100" ry="50" fill="yellow"></ellipse>
</svg>
```

The viewport size defaults to 300x150 thus everything else gets cropped.