# SVG script in http

Tags: javascript, html

We have an SVG script and i just want to know if it is safe to reference it as http?

```
var ns = { 'svg': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' };
```

I have tried making it as https but it breaks my icons.
Is it possible to make it https?

Comment: the `http` version is the one supplied in Mozilla docs    
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/script

Comment: does it have an https version?

Comment: not that I know of, I am pretty sure you can just leave it out.

Comment: here is some info for you   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467982/are-svg-parameters-such-as-xmlns-and-version-needed

Comment: It's a namespace, not a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *namespace* (hint: look at the variable name `ns`!). This address will not be fetched, it is just used to indicate which specifications have been used to create this SVG markup. So it is safe for it not to be HTTPS since no data will actually be exchanged with this address.