# How to modify svg icon colors with Tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm using TailwindCSS and want to change the color of an svg. Without Tailwind this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element), for 2020 [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53336754/7764329) should be a good answer but Tailwind does not support those filters. There is a guide in the docs on [how to work with svg icons](https://tailwindcss.com/course/working-with-svg-icons) but this tutorial works without files, just the plain text paths.

I downloaded the svg files and assign the path to the svg to the image's `src` tag. The following example shows my problem, I want the icon's background to be red and the icon's color to be blue. Unfortunately it's not possible for me to change the icon color.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@1.8.10/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- taken from here https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/765208/media_twitter_social_icon -->
<img class="fill-current bg-red-500 text-blue-500" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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">
```

What is the correct workflow when downloading svg icons and use them directly by linking the assets path? All I want to achieve is something like this

```
<a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
  <img src="pathToSvgInAssetsFolder" />
</a>
```

and set the icon color to a custom Tailwind color e.g. `red-500`. So whenever I want to change the icon color I can simply modify the color class.

Does someone know how to do it?

Comment: There is no workflow for using SVG as images unless the SVG is designed exactly as you want it to appear. Why not use inline SVG?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean? I tried this https://jsfiddle.net/e0o8ctmg/

Comment: This will be helpful https://tailwindcss.com/docs/fill

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The workflow for adding SVG to your Tailwind project should be done using [inline SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web#How_to_include_SVG_code_inside_your_HTML).

Adam Watham the creator of Tailwind CSS made a [video](https://tailwindcss.com/course/working-with-svg-icons) about working with inline SVG in Tailwind. In the video he shows a workflow you would use to prep an unoptimized SVG for a Tailwind project. Here's the steps with one extra step he didn't mention:

1. Drop the SVG file or paste the SVG markup into the optimizer at [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/).
2. Copy the markup provided by SVGOMG and paste into your project.
3. Remove any fill or stroke attributes so Tailwind can modify those with classes (not shown in the video).
4. Remove any XMLNS attributes or XML tags, these are [not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18468348/7657915) for inline SVG.
5. Add Tailwind classes.

If you're using a component based framework it's recommended that you also [extract](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/extracting-components) the icons into components that can be reused throughout your application.

The benefits of this approach:

- Full control over the size and color of your SVG icons
- Faster load speed since the icons are part of the HTML

Here's an example based on the Fiddle you shared in the comments. I ran the SVGs through SVGOMG and removed the fill attributes so Tailwind can control that.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@1.8.10/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<svg class="text-teal-500 fill-current h-16 w-16" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
    <path d="M41.05 18.44a6.6 6.6 0 00-4.84-2.29c-3.66-.06-6.62 3.04-6.62 6.91 0 .55.05 1.09.17 1.6a18.68 18.68 0 01-13.66-7.55 7.33 7.33 0 00-.9 3.55 7.3 7.3 0 002.95 5.92 6.34 6.34 0 01-3-.92v.1c0 3.42 2.28 6.3 5.31 6.97a6.24 6.24 0 01-3 .1 6.74 6.74 0 006.2 4.93 12.8 12.8 0 01-9.81 2.9A17.89 17.89 0 0024 43.85c12.19 0 18.86-10.61 18.86-19.81l-.02-.9c1.3-.97 2.42-2.18 3.3-3.56-1.18.54-2.46.9-3.8 1.04a6.8 6.8 0 002.91-3.8c-1.28.77-2.7 1.33-4.2 1.62z"/>
</svg>

<svg class="bg-red-500 text-red-800 fill-current h-16 w-16 rounded-lg" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
    <path d="M25.46 47.31V30h-3.52v-5.74h3.52v-3.47c0-4.68 1.4-8.06 6.53-8.06h6.1v5.73h-4.3c-2.15 0-2.64 1.43-2.64 2.92v2.88h6.62l-.9 5.74h-5.72V47.3h-5.69z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Step 5 says Add Tailwind classes. Do we do anything other than [Fill](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/fill), [Stroke](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/stroke) and [Stroke Width](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/stroke-width)? I was wondering if the answer should be more specific?

Comment: For me, the missing part was the **fill-current** class

Comment: I tried this and the svg is not picking up the color. Are these instructions still accurate?

Comment: @Mel it still works on Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/vsSEXCEuTq which runs the most current version of Tailwind. Is your Tailwind CLI build process running?

Comment: @Pjotr Same for me. SVGs' color would not update unless I added a `fill-current` class.

Comment: What if I want to change an icon? Should I find&replace all its appearances in my project? What if this same icon was optimised differently in different places in my code or edited manually so that they don't match each other letter by letter? You will have to find each icon manually and edit it. Now imagine updating the whole icon set. Also if you load your svg from your /public folder you can cache it while here you duplicate it all the time in html. Not to mention you pollute your code with this svg path stuff. IMHO inline svg is a very bad solution in terms of programming experience.

Comment: @OlegYablokov It's easiest to build a reusable component that inserts the path data into an SVG element. Then when an icon needs to be updated you just update the path data. The only pollution would happen in the rendered HTML in the browser, users don't care. Also inline SVG prevents multiple round trips to the server, loads instantly with the HTML and SVG icons (when made correctly) are so small they have almost no impact on the overall size of the HTML sent to the client. But thanks for sharing your humble opinion on the matter.

Comment: @JHeth good point about multiple round trips, I've missed that. Sure, I guess I will write some MySvg component for that. BTW if anyone finds a library for that so that one doesn't have to write their own custom svg component please drop a link to it here

Comment: UPD: I've found such a library for those who use React, see my [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77511275/7114988)

Answer (score 9):

In simple terms use `text-<color>` and `fill-current`

```
<svg class="h-16 w-16 rounded-full bg-cyan-400 fill-current text-white" viewBox="0 0 60 60">
  <path d="M25.46 47.31V30h-3.52v-5.74h3.52v-3.47c0-4.68 1.4-8.06 6.53-8.06h6.1v5.73h-4.3c-2.15 0-2.64 1.43-2.64 2.92v2.88h6.62l-.9 5.74h-5.72V47.3h-5.69z" />
</svg>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't it work with just `fill-color-100`? Why do I need to use `text-color` instead of this?

Comment: @Flamingo because icons (and decorations in general) are often used alongside text and expected to use the same color as the surrounding text, so it just makes things easier to have stroke or fill default to text color.
"current" is also bigger than Tailwind, as it's part of CSS itself - https://css-tricks.com/currentcolor/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Heroicons try `stroke-cyan-500` and `fill-cyan-300` tags.

See:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/fill

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/stroke

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the idea of inline SVG, see the comments section in the accepted answer. So I've found an alternative solution for those who use React. The idea is to generate a React component for each .svg file:

1. Install [SVGR command line](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/cli).
2. Generate React components, e.g.: `npx @svgr/cli --no-dimensions --typescript --out-dir src/components/icons_svg -- public/icons_svg`.
3. Remove all `fill` entries from the generated code: `sed -i '' -e 's/fill=".*"//g' $(find src/components/icons_svg -type f -not -path "*path/to/your/colored/MySvg.tsx*")`. The `MySvg.tsx` can be a component that shouldn't be `fill`-ed with color because it represents an already colored svg.
4. Use the generated components: `<SvgLogo className="h-4 w-4 fill-red" />`.

Answer (score -1):

The simple way to change SVG color is to set `class="fill-current"`  on the SVG tag and then set the color like the text on it like this :

I set `text-blue-400`

```
  //bell icon
  <svg viewBox="0 0 46 48" class="fill-current text-blue-400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M23.0002 0C12.5068 0 4.00017 8.50659 4.00017 19V32.5335C4.00017 32.8383 3.9145 33.1371 3.75292 33.3956L0.912672 37.94C0.0801118 39.2721 1.0378 41 2.60867 41H43.3917C44.9625 41 45.9202 39.2721 45.0877 37.94L42.2474 33.3956C42.0858 33.1371 42.0002 32.8383 42.0002 32.5335V19C42.0002 8.50659 33.4936 0 23.0002 0ZM23.0002 48C20.2388 48 18.0002 45.7614 18.0002 43H28.0002C28.0002 45.7614 25.7616 48 23.0002 48Z"></path>
  </svg>
```

[image]