# Render SVG string to DOM via DOMParser SVG namespace

Tags: javascript, svg, dom, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to parse a SVG element from a string and render it into the DOM but when I parse as `image/svg+xml`, the `<svg>` gets appended into the DOM in some strange way that does not render it (at least in Firefox). When I parse as `text/html`, it does render but adds an undesired `xmlns` attribute.

Is there some way to still parse as `image/svg+xml` (because that's what it is) while having it render? I tried [document.adoptNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/adoptNode) but it did not help.

This does not render:

```js
const svg = '<svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16" height="16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.75 2a.75.75 0 0 1 .75.75V7h4.25a.75.75 0 1 1 0 1.5H8.5v4.25a.75.75 0 1 1-1.5 0V8.5H2.75a.75.75 0 0 1 0-1.5H7V2.75A.75.75 0 0 1 7.75 2z"/></svg>';
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(svg, 'image/svg+xml');
document.body.appendChild(doc.documentElement);
```

This renders, but includes undesired `xmlns` attribute:

```js
const svg = '<svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16" height="16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.75 2a.75.75 0 0 1 .75.75V7h4.25a.75.75 0 1 1 0 1.5H8.5v4.25a.75.75 0 1 1-1.5 0V8.5H2.75a.75.75 0 0 1 0-1.5H7V2.75A.75.75 0 0 1 7.75 2z"/></svg>';
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(svg, 'text/html');
document.body.appendChild(doc.body.firstChild);
```

Comment: why is an xmlns attribute undesirable? Note the first case should render if you actually use the proper xmlns attributes.

Comment: Just checked your code in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/wj1rz2ub  I see rendered <svg> without xmlns attribute

Comment: I see that the first example renders when adding the `xmlns`. I just thought it undesirable because in HTML (the target document), the attribute is optional and I prefer to keep things minimal. So I guess that answers the question already. `xmlns` is not optional when parsing for the SVG namespace, but is for the HTML namespace.

Comment: It's not really optional, as your SVG needs it to be rendered properly. Trust me, you want to add `xmlns` if possible to avoid weird glitches with SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DOMParser()` interface has a method `parseFromString(string, mimeType)` which parses a string containing either HTML or XML & returns an HTMLDocument or an XMLDocument.

The second parameter `mimeType` determines whether to use `XML parser` or the `HTML parser`. Only `text/html` will invoke the HTML parser, and any other valid MIME type will invoke the XML parser [refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString)

So, it will work as :

```js
const svg = '<svg height="100" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle r="45" cx="50" cy="50" fill="grey" /></svg> ';
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(svg, 'image/svg+xml');
const svgImg = doc.querySelector("svg")
document.body.appendChild(svgImg);
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Parsing SVG using DOMParser()</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The issues comes down to the `xmlns` attribute which is required when parsing for the SVG mime type but optional in the HTML one, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18468348/808699.

Given that SVG is considered a foreign element in HTML, it's prefered to parse it as `text/html` if one wants to omit the `xmlns` attribute.